# Unable to scrape all photos even after using selenium to automate scroll

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver, dynamic-html

I am a newbie to web scraping. I am currently working on a project where I want to scrape all the photos of an instagram user. The user has 521 posts in total due to which I had used selenium to scroll down till the bottom of the profile. But I am still able to scrape only the first 37 photos. After further inspecting, I found that as the browser scrolls up or down, only the first few rows of img tags are visible in the source code. As I scroll more, the previously visible img tags disappear and only the next rows are visible. So only a certain no. of rows are visible in the html code at any instant. I doubt it to be the reason why I am able to scrape only the first 37 photos.

I want to know how I can scrape all the photos of the profile. Below I have mentioned my current code using Beautiful Soup and Selenium. Here, "scroll_down" function uses selenium to scroll down till the bottom of the profile. I am trying to scrape all the 'img' tags in the function "downloading_images", but as already mentioned, I am able to scrape only first 37 photos.

```
def downloading_images(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source,'html.parser')
        self.all_images = soup.findAll('img')
        print(len(self.all_images))

        for index,image in enumerate(self.all_images):
            filename = "image_" + str(index) + ".jpg"
            image_path = os.path.join(self.path,filename)
            link = image['src']
            print("Downloading image ", index)

            response = requests.get(link,stream = True)
            try:
                with open(image_path,'wb') as file:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw,file)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print('Could not download image no.', index)
                print('Image link',link)

def scroll_down(self):
        sleep(3)
        try:
            num_posts = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()[contains(.," posts")]]/span[@class="g47SY "]')
            str_num_posts = str(num_posts.text).replace(',','')
            self.int_num_posts = int(str_num_posts)

            if self.int_num_posts > 12:
                num_scrolls = int(self.int_num_posts/12) + 3

            print(num_scrolls)
            sleep(3)
            try:
                for win in range(num_scrolls):
                    print(win)
                    self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
                    sleep(3)
            except Exception as e:
                self.error = True
                print(e)
        except Exception as e:
            self.error = True
            print(e)
```

I searched for all relevant questions here, but none of them could help me understand how I can fetch those images from the code which keeps disappearing upon scrolling.
Hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Ok, I tried to scrape upon every scroll and it seems to work. Here is my new code.

```
def downloading_images(self):

        print(len(self.all_images))



        for index,image in enumerate(self.all_images):
            filename = "image_" + str(index) + ".jpg"
            image_path = os.path.join(self.path,filename)
            link = image['src']
            print("Downloading image ", index)

            response = requests.get(link,stream = True)
            try:
                with open(image_path,'wb') as file:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw,file)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print('Could not download image no.', index)
                print('Image link',link)






    def scroll_down(self):
        sleep(3)
        try:
            num_posts = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()[contains(.," posts")]]/span[@class="g47SY "]')
            str_num_posts = str(num_posts.text).replace(',','')
            self.int_num_posts = int(str_num_posts)

            if self.int_num_posts > 12:
                num_scrolls = int(self.int_num_posts/12) + 1

            else:
                num_scrolls = self.int_num_posts

            print(num_scrolls)
            sleep(3)
            try:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source,'html.parser')
                images = soup.findAll('img')
                
                self.all_images = images
                last_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
                for win in range(num_scrolls):
                    print(win)
                    self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
                    sleep(3)
                    new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
                    if new_height == last_height:
                        break
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source,'html.parser')
                    images = soup.findAll('img')
                    self.all_images.extend(images[-12:])
                    last_height = new_height

                print(len(self.all_images))
            except Exception as e:
                self.error = True
                print(e)
        except Exception as e:
            self.error = True
            print(e)



    def search_target(self):
        try:
            search_bar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="XTCLo x3qfX "]')
            search_bar.send_keys(self.target_username)
            taget_profile_url = self.main_url + '/' + self.target_username + '/'
            self.driver.get(taget_profile_url)
        except Exception as e:
            self.error = True
            print(e)


    def close_notify_box(self):
        try:
            sleep(3)
            not_now_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="aOOlW   HoLwm "]')
            not_now_button.click()
        except Exception:
            pass


    def log_in(self):
        try:
            log_in_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="izU2O"]/a')
            log_in_button.click()
            sleep(3)
            user_name_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@aria-label="Phone number, username, or email"]')
            user_name_input.send_keys(self.username)
            password_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@aria-label="Password"]')
            password_input.send_keys(self.password)
            password_input.submit()
        except Exception as e:
            self.error = True
            print(e)
```

I would like to know if there are any alternative solutions to this. And whether it is an efficient solution. Thank you.

Comment: you may want to take a look at https://github.com/RonLek/InstaScraper

Comment: @JackFleeting I tried running the code in your mentioned link. It scraps the **last** 30 pictures only. My code has similar issue, but it scrapes **first** 37 pictures. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Not yet; I tried another, totally different, code on a random Instagram account and managed to get 33 out of 45 images. I'll try again tomorrow...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am trying it for past two days. Hope I find it out.